# Отслеживание работы процессов в Windows Java

Tags: java, windows

Всем доброго времени суток! Пишу программу у которая отслеживает работу выбранных программ. Как сделать так чтобы java отслеживала запуск .exe файлов программы и мониторила их закрытие?

Comment: Те закорючки после `tasklist`, т.е. `|>` - это же команды cmd.exe, который Вы не используете. Вместо этого передаёте как параметры в tasklist, А он из не понимает, и вероятно отказывается работать так, как Вы хоттите. Попробуйте вывести результтат `process,waitFor()`.  Обычно 0 - если процесс отработал нормально, и != 0 когда возникла ошибка.

Comment: Доброго дня! У меня не так много опыта в подобной работе :( была мысль считывать tasklist и находить там искомые процессы, но это считывание и поиск придется зациклить чтобы каждый раз убеждаться что процессы работают и мне кажется это не выход. Я нашел process.waitFor(), но не получается связать с мониторингом этих процессов. В коде process.waitFor() отрабатывает с ошибкой

Comment: Из жавы легко следить только за процессами, которые запущенны из самой жавы. За tasklist-ом в Вашем случае (если правильно его запустить, конечно:) А если процесс запущен вне жавы, то это трудно. Разработчики жавы не предусмотрели ничего такого. Им наверное даже мысль такая в голову не приходила. Можно составить функции на c|c++ и вызывать из из жавы с помощью JNI или JNA. Или сделать вспомогательную программу на c|c++ и общаться с ней по своему протоколу.